# Add border radius on table row

Tags: css, angular, typescript, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am using a datagrid to present some information.

I want to add border radius to all the rows in my table, but I'm not getting it.

Does anyone know how I can add border-radius to all rows in the table?

Is there a way to put the text fully aligned to the left and "remove" the column that is there, but without delete indexing?

Thanks

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t6957g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

**Code**

```
<dx-data-grid class="tableTask" id="gridContainer" [dataSource]="Data" [remoteOperations]="false"
    [allowColumnReordering]="true" [showRowLines]="false" [showColumnLines]="false" [rowAlternationEnabled]="true"
    [showBorders]="false">   
    <dxo-group-panel [visible]="true"></dxo-group-panel>
    <dxo-grouping [autoExpandAll]="false"></dxo-grouping>
    <dxi-column dataField="name" [groupIndex]="0"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="name" dataType="string"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="name1" dataType="string"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="name2" dataType="string"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="name3" dataType="string" [width]="150"></dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `border-radius` directly to the table cells (first and last child):

```
 ::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-rowsview .dx-data-row td:first-child {
   border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
   border-top-left-radius: 8px;
 }

  ::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-rowsview .dx-data-row td:last-child {
   border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
   border-top-right-radius: 8px;
 }
```

Comment: Do you know how I can hide the class dx-command-expand dx-datagrid-group-space in order to align the text entirely to the left?

Comment: Well, you can add `display: none` to the first child and move the left border radius to another selector -> `td:nth-child(2)`, but you should play around to make it look good, because of the upper rows.